# Creating OpenerView in a Notebook for Various Section of the Notebook in Mathematica

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica

I have a notebook with various sections which I would like to contract (i.e show only the title of the section/subsection etc...) and expand as needed to reveal more or less of the content of the various parts (as done in the help section of Mathematica for instance).

I see the function OpenerView creates the icon but appears not to be suited for the purpose.
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Should this question be migrated to superuser?

Answer (score 2):

From the menu, try "Format->Option Inspector" and select "Selected Notebook" from the drop-down menu. Then in the search box type "opener", and make sure the "ShowGroupOpener" is checked. Then put the parts of your document into "Sections", "Subsections" etc. using the "Format->Style" menu options.

Comment: I have done as you indicate, but the icon seems to control only whether the output of the evaluation shows or not. What I am trying to hide/expand is the possibly unevaluated text under the section/subsections etc. which may contain program code or plain text. Or is there a particular way to specify the text/code under the specific heading?

Answer (score 1):

The blue brackets on the right side of the page are cell brackets.  They show you want can or will be collapsed.  Double click the one that surrounds the block you wish to collapse, or select the section and press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>

If you wish to expand or collapse all of the sections within a section or notebook, select the range you want to affect (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all), then use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to open
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to close

---

In the menu `Cell`>`Grouping` if `Manual Grouping` rather than `Automatic Grouping` is selected, then the sections you want to collapse may not actually be grouped.  You can see what is grouped or not, by the blue brackets on the right side of the Notebook.  This is what I attempted to allude to above.  If you change the setting to `Automatic Grouping`, or group the cells manually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, you should see the brackets indicate the group, and the commands above should work.

Comment: I clearly must be missing something. it does not change at all. are there settings i have to configure beforehand?

Comment: @Phil, I am sorry that I did not provide a helpful answer.  I don't have time to work on this right now, but I will revisit it later.

Comment: @Phil, one thing now, under menu Cell > Grouping, is Manual or Automatic selected?

Comment: @Mr. I can reproduce Phil's symptoms by setting the Cell->Grouping to Manual. Good catch.

Comment: One possibility with Mma 7 Mathematica is to use `Preferences -> Interface -> Show Open/Close Icons for Cell
Groups` (on a Mac System).  The OpenViewer icon
(side-triangle) then appears with the leading cell of all grouped cells in a notebook. Another possibility, suggested by David Park (see [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Apr/msg01019.html) ) is to add `ShowGroupOpenCloseIcon->True` to, say, a Sectional Cell expression (using `Show Expression`, for instance)

Comment: I don't know what OS the OP is on, but on OS X the keyboard shortcuts are Cmd-... instead of Ctrl-...

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to this post,
 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265/easiest-way-to-use-showgroupopener-in-mathematica

it will likely have your answer. To enter the expression for the cell, use Cell | Show Expression. There you can turn on the ShowGroupHeader option.